# Modificar comandos de artisan

Tags: laravel, script, línea-de-comandos, artisan

Trabajo con Laravel 5.8 en un entorno Windows, y también, desde otro ordenador, en un entorno Ubuntu. Me gustaría saber como puedo modificar el comportamiento de un comando de Artisan.

En concreto, me interesa el comando `php artisan make:controller` de forma que, al crear un controlador, incluya, por defecto, el método constructor del mismo (algo que el comando existente no hace).

Me imagino que los comandos de Artisan serán scripts que estarán en "alguna parte" del directorio `vendor`, pero no sé donde, ni como editarlos o, si creo un comando nuevo con `php artisan make:command`, no sé con qué lenguaje o sintaxis programarlo para que haga lo que sea para lo que lo conciba.

En la documentación de Laravel no he encontrado nada a este respecto. ¿Alguien sabe dónde puedo documentarme y aprender esto?

Comment: Puedes ver el código del comando en el repositorio de Laravel [ControllerMakeCommand.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Routing/Console/ControllerMakeCommand.php), y basándote en eso, crear tu propio comando personalizado (`CustomControllerMakeCommand` o como quieres llamarle). Básicamente, tendrías que crear un archivo de plantilla `stub`, que es como un plano de cómo se verá el nuevo archivo del Controller que vayas a crear. Y en tu comando personalizado indicarle que lo use por defecto o pasándole alguna opción al comando.

Comment: Aunque hice una búsqueda rápida y encontré que al parecer puedes extender directamente tu comando del que trae laravel `CustomControllerMakeCommand extends ControllerMakeCommand`. Está en inglés pero te puede servir [How to customize controllers generated by Artisan](https://blog.vigilantmedia.com/2015/08/07/how-to-customize-controllers-generated-by-artisan-in-laravel). Y en este otro puedes ver como hacer que le agregue el constructor a la clase creada [Make custom class using console command](https://techsemicolon.github.io/blog/2019/01/11/laravel-make-custom-class-using-console-command)